# how to open downloaded excel file when complete download in asp .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

We have a web server, which allows the user to download files (excel), which are dynamically-generated  We'd like  when a download has completed then it should automatically open client side in the excel.

is there any way to do so by asp.net code or jquery code or javascript code?

Comment: but i want to open excel file open from browser what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. You can't tell the client-side how to handle downloaded files.

Imagine the security issues that would cause.
*"you just (accidentally?) downloaded `someShiftyFile.pdf.exe`, now we MAKE your pc run it!"*

Possibilities like that would make virus coders very happy.

Comment: but i want to open excel file open from browser what to do?

Comment: @ChiragSutariya: Just provide a url to the excel file. (like: `http://my.server.com/files/excelFile.xls` The browser then decides how to handle the file.